# Jquery adding background to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some problems in jQuery but before that let me give a summary.

What I am doing is imitating the TF2 Drop System and Crafting, but I have only started the drop system (for people who play it).

For people who do not do it, I am basically setting a chance for the user to get a weapon or a crate everytime the function repeats.

When the user gets it, I want the background of the first div without a background image to change accordingly to the weapon or crate.

Cut the crap short and here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="tf2.jpg"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="interface.css"/>
    <title>TF2 Idler</title>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.0.js">  
        var random;
        var id;
        var items = [
            "holymackerel.png",
            "caber.jpg"
        ];  
        function update() {
            if(String($('#a1').attr('style')).indexOf(this) == -1){
                 $('#a1').css("background-image", "url('" + items[id] + "')");
            }
            else if (String($('#a2').attr('style')).indexOf(this) == -1){
                 $('#a2').css("background-image", "url('" + items[id] + "')");
            }
        }
        setInterval(function() {
            random = 100 * (Math.random());
            if (random <= 10){
                if (random < 5) {
                    id = 0;
                    update();
                }
                else if (random <= 10) {
                    id = 1;
                    update();
                }
            }
            else if (random > 10 && random <= 35) {
                //get crate
            }
        },5000);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="invent">
        <div id="page1">
            <div class="slot" id="a1"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a2"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a3"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a4"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a5"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a6"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a7"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a8"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a9"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a10"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a11"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a12"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a13"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a14"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a15"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a16"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a17"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a18"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a19"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a20"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a21"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a22"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a23"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a24"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a25"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a26"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a27"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a28"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a29"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a30"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a31"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a32"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a33"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a34"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a35"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a36"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a37"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a38"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a39"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a40"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a41"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a42"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a43"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a44"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a45"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a46"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a47"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a48"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a49"></div>
            <div class="slot" id="a50"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Important: Don't use same script tag with src attribute and code

Comment: Even if I am using jQuery, a javascript library?

Comment: __Always__ doesn't matter What

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Satpal wrote: Don't use the same script tag where external JS loaded for the code. So the valid version see below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="tf2.jpg"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="interface.css"/>
    <title>TF2 Idler</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var random;
        var id;
        var items = [
            "holymackerel.png",
            "caber.jpg"
        ];
        function update() {
            if (String($('#a1').attr('style')).indexOf(this) == -1) {
                $('#a1').css("background-image", "url('" + items[id] + "')");
            }
            else if (String($('#a2').attr('style')).indexOf(this) == -1) {
                $('#a2').css("background-image", "url('" + items[id] + "')");
            }
        }
        setInterval(function () {
            random = 100 * (Math.random());
            if (random <= 10) {
                if (random < 5) {
                    id = 0;
                    update();
                }
                else if (random <= 10) {
                    id = 1;
                    update();
                }
            }
            else if (random > 10 && random <= 35) {
                //get crate
            }
        }, 5000);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="invent">
    <div id="page1">
        <div class="slot" id="a1"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a2"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a3"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a4"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a5"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a6"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a7"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a8"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a9"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a10"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a11"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a12"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a13"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a14"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a15"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a16"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a17"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a18"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a19"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a20"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a21"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a22"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a23"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a24"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a25"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a26"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a27"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a28"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a29"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a30"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a31"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a32"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a33"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a34"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a35"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a36"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a37"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a38"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a39"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a40"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a41"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a42"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a43"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a44"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a45"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a46"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a47"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a48"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a49"></div>
        <div class="slot" id="a50"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```